# I am unable to catch exception in php code

Tags: php, exception

I have following piece of code:

```
function doSomething()
{
     try {
         doSomeNastyStuff() // throws Exception
     } catch(\Exception $e) {
         if ($this->errorHandler) {
             call_user_func($e);
         } else {
             throw($e);
         }
     }
}
```

However, the catch block does not work. The stack trace shows me the error happened at the line `doSomeNastyStuff()`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you are rethrowing your Exception. The stack trace is part of the `Exception` instance and is recorded at the moment, exception is created. You can get the stack trace by

```
 $e->getTrace(); // Exception $e
```

When you rethrow exception in your code, it still has the old stack trace recorded and this tricks your framework to show you, the exception actually happened at the line `doSomeNastyStuff()` and it seems like the `catch` does not work.

Therefore, it is better idea to rethrow exceptions the following way:

```
/** instead of throw($e) do */
throw new \Exception("Unhandled exception", 1, $e);
```

Beginining with php5.3, `Exception constructor` has optional third parameter `$previous` exactly for this purpose. You can then get the previous `Exception` using `$e->getPrevious();`